# Setting current user for required model field

Tags: python, django

I have a model where one of the required fields is the currently signed in user. I do the following when creating a new record for the model:

views.py

```
def post(self, request):
    bound_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if bound_form.is_valid():
        new_position = bound_form.save()
```

The problem is that this only works when the user has selected them self on the form. I need a way to set the current user automatically and simply don't display the user field on the form. I have tried this:

```
def post(self, request):
    bound_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if bound_form.is_valid():
        new_position = bound_form.save(commit=False)
        new_position.user = request.user
        new_position.save()
```

However this does not work because the `bound_form` is not valid because it is missing a user which is a required field on the model. Where else can the user be set before trying to save the form? In the template, or the get method of the view?

Comment: You should do exactly what you've done, except that you need to exclude the user field from the form in the first place.

Comment: Im not sure im following. I currently only show the fields that I want the user to fill in (ie: I have removed the user field). In other words,...everything works if the user selects themselves, but if I remove the field so that they can't select themself then I cant save the form even with the above code.

Comment: You should use `exclude=('user',)` in `class Meta:` of your `form`

Comment: ahah,...I see what you mean. Thanks. That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `exclude=('user',)` in `class Meta:` of your `form`. @Daniel Roseman is also right.